# How to get split value with comma into select input in HTML

Tags: php, html, sql

I have a database table Column with split value separated by a comma, find below an example:

```
     ID  CARS 
     1   Toyota, Lexus, Benz
```

I will like a query that will return Toyota, Lexus, Benz as an array and have it display on the Select dropdown on an HTML form like below:

```
<select name="cars" id="cars">
    <option value="Toyota">Toyota</option>
    <option value="Lexus">Lexus</option>
    <option value="Benz">Benz</option>
  </select>
```

I need a query to do this and also PHP code to display them on the Select dropdown. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, this is not a service to get your code written. This is a service to ask for help if you can not figure something specific out (and have tried).

Comment: Am only asking for a query that will get those value out as list and get it on select

Comment: Can you tell us what you have tried so far? Edit your question showing us what you tried and we'll try to figure out why it did not work.

Comment: @DownloadPizza thanks someone helped out already without editing. I really appreciate it, can you please add my question to part of the useful questions so to help other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can solve this problem using [PHP code](https://phpize.online/?phpses=46af11b1857907961de39e1b2782dc80&sqlses=a1e4b96b1a5b09f2d9f00322b90f770b&php_version=php8&sql_version=mysql80):

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT cars FROM cars WHERE id = 1;";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$cars = explode(',', $row['cars']);

foreach($cars as $car) {
    $car = trim($car);
    echo "<option value=\"$car\">$car</option>" . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use $options preg_split(“,”, $sql);